# UVM Verbosity override

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there a way to override any verbosity switches that have been given and force verbosity to a different value in UVM?

```
+uvm_set_verbosity=*abc*,_ALL_,UVM_FULL,run 
+uvm_set_verbosity=*aes*,_ALL_,UVM_FULL,run 
+uvm_set_verbosity=*sel*,_ALL_,UVM_FULL,run 
+uvm_set_verbosity=*init*,_ALL_,UVM_FULL,run
```

For example if cmdline has these switches, what is the easiest way to quiet all these high verbosity without removing individual switches?

Answer (score 1):

Hunting around in the source code of UVM I found the `set_report_verbosity_level_hier` function in `uvm_component`. You could call that on `uvm_root` and set it (quite indiscriminately) to whatever low value you fancy.

```
initial begin
    uvm_root root;
    root = uvm_root::get();
    root.set_report_verbosity_level_hier(UVM_LOW);
    // Whatever you do here.
end
```

If you want to do that only for some `id`s you should be able to do that with `set_report_id_verbosity_hier`.

Notice I just tested the snippet above in a dumb testbench without even a test, so it might have problems with a real-world setup. If you have a more complex phasing of verbosity settings for your components you will need to override them each time they are applied, or toy with `m_verbosity_settings` directly.